# What is this funny/strange black thing on the nail of my guinea pig?

Tags: grooming, guinea-pigs

This morning, I was cutting my guinea pigs nails and I discovered that the bit of nail on the back foot has gone black and strange and I never saw this before. 
Needless to say, I am quite worried about this. Do you have any ideas? What might cause this? How do I stop it from getting worse?

See this picture:

[image]

Comment: it looks like old blood so you need to take it to your vet to get it cleaned and treated.

Answer (score 2):

[NOT A VET]
This looks like the nail has been torn off and the tissue underneath is undergoing necrosis. I suggest seeing a vet, it looks a bit swollen so it is probably infected.